# Cut string according to pixel width

Tags: css

Is it possible to do something like

```
if (width > 1000px)
   substr(str, 0, 10);
else
   substr(str, 0, 5);
```

using media queries in pure CSS?

I know there is a *line clamping* that actually works https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Is there any similar CSS property (set of properties) for the other dimension approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "other dimension approach"?

Comment: you could just disable the overflow on the element you want to clip